# Missing return in a function expected to return 'Double?'

Tags: swift

I'm grinding through Apple's App Development with Swift book and I have been having a few issues with the Optionals sections.

I'm getting stuck accessing a dictionary after I have accessed another dictionary to return an optional value that meets a condition. The error being returned is:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'Double?'

```
var prices = ["Chips": 2.99, "Donuts": 1.89, "Juice": 3.99, "Apple": 0.50, "Banana": 0.25, "Broccoli": 0.99]
var stock = ["Chips": 4, "Donuts": 0, "Juice": 12, "Apple": 6, "Banana": 6, "Broccoli": 3]

func priceCheck(name: String) -> Double? {
    let pricefinder = name
    if let name = stock[name] {
        print(name)
        if name > 0 {
            if let pricefinder = prices[pricefinder] {
                print(pricefinder)
                return pricefinder
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong with the code above? I need to check if a product is in stock and then return its price if that condition evaluates to true.

And is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function can be shortened a hell of a lot by taking advantage of some of the tools that’s Swift gives you. Here, take a look, this does the same thing...

```
func priceCheck(name: String) -> Double? {
    guard let stockAmount = stock[name],
        stockAmount > 0,
        let price = prices[name] else {
        return nil
    }

    return price
}
```

Comment: That `prices[name]` unwrap is not needed, you can directly return `prices[name]`.

Comment: Mentioned as an alternative approach in my answer :)

Comment: @Sulthan true. Guess it depends how the OP wants to handle the missing price. But yes, you’re right :-)

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister this is really good. I just checked the book and there's a whole section on using guard with optionals that helped unpack this concept for me.

Comment: @RhysEdwards no worries. Happy to help. Never stop learning :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is merely that you have not covered all cases in your logic. What if `name` is *not* greater than zero? Your code does not say what to do. Thus you fail to return a value in that situation:

```
func priceCheck(name: String) -> Double? {
    let pricefinder = name
    if let name = stock[name] {
        print(name)
        if name > 0 {
            if let pricefinder = prices[pricefinder] {
                print(pricefinder)
                return pricefinder
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } else { // this is the question: what if it isn't?
            return nil // ???? I don't know what you want to do...
            // ... but you MUST return something in this situation
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Listen to the compiler. It knows more than you do.

Answer (score 2):

As a pretty quick solution, all you have to do is to add `return nil` at the end of your function:

```
func priceCheck(name: String) -> Double? {
    let pricefinder = name
    if let name = stock[name] {
        print(name)
        if name > 0 {
            if let pricefinder = prices[pricefinder] {
                print(pricefinder)
                return pricefinder
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }

    // here we go:
    return nil
}
```

because at some point (name is *not* greater than 0), the function does not returns anything.

Also, note that you could implement your function -as a shorter version- as:

```
func priceCheck(name: String) -> Double? {
    let pricefinder = name
    if let name = stock[name], name > 0 {
        if let pricefinder = prices[pricefinder] {
            return pricefinder
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

If the function returns nil at the end of it, there is no point of adding `else { return nil }` for each `if`; Or you could even use `guard` statement to achieve it as mentioned in [Fogmeister`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722837/5501940).

Comment: If you are going to add a "catch all" `return nil` at the end, then I suggest removing all of the redundant `else { return nil }` statements. Only have the `return pricefinder` that returns a real value and the one "catch all" return at the end.

Comment: Yes @rmaddy, that's exactly what I mentioned in my update :)

Comment: There are a few other confusing things about the OP's code that could use some cleanup. The function's parameter is called `name` but then a new `name` constant is introduced in the first `if let`. And `pricefinder` is needlessly copied from the original parameter due to the confusing 2nd `name` constant.

Comment: you can just return `prices[pricefinder]` and invert the condition: `guard let name = stock[name], name > 0 else { return nil }`